# How to generate the time series from a given model?

Tags: r, regression, time-series, sas

We consider a sparse autoregressive time series of length 1000 obeying the model

$$X(t)=0.2X(t-1)+0.1X(t-3)+0.2X(t-5)+0.3X(t-10)+0.1X(t-15)+Z(t)$$

with nonzero coefficients at lags 1,3,5,10 and 15,where the innovations Z(t) are i.i.d. Gaussians with mean zero and standard deviation 0.1.

The question is how to simulate 1000 time series from the model with R or SAS?

Comment: So how would you define $X(0)$ and $X(1)$?  In your case, you either need the fifteen initial values, and then the rest can be built, or you need to specify the distribution that $X(i)$ are drawn from, for $i<15$ *and* whether the model allows the lags to be brought in as and when they are available, i.e. is $X(t-15) = 0$ if $t<15$?

Answer (score 1):

In R, fill a vector with Gaussian white noise of zero mean and sd 0.1, then use the `filter` function. Notice that since the first 15 observations are white noise (and thence not generated by your model), you have to discard a section of your generated observations (say 10 times the maximum lag).

Answer (score 1):

This is another way of simulating the result using `arima.sim`. It includes the code and some simple checks.

```
# Test it on a more well behaved model:
n <- 10000
n.sub <- 9000
maxlag <- 15
x <- arima.sim(n=n,list(ar=c(0,0,0,0,.5)),rand.gen=rnorm,sd=0.1)
x <- x[n-n.sub:1]
acf(x,lag.max=maxlag,type="partial")            # check!
armod <- ar(x,order.max=maxlag,method="mle")
armod       # check!
resi <- armod$resid[(1+maxlag):length(armod$resid)]
qqplot(y=resi,x=rnorm(n.sub-maxlag))          # normal residuals
qqline(resi,probs=c(.3,.7))
mean(resi)
sd(resi)                                      # distributionally proper

# For your example:
n <- 2000
n.sub <- 1000
x <- arima.sim(n=n,list(ar=c(.2,0,.1,0,.2,0,0,0,0,.3,0,0,0,0,.1)),rand.gen=rnorm,sd=0.1)
x <- x[n-n.sub:1]
```